# windows phone 8.1 silverlight mediaelement auto rotate

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-8.1

I am new in windows phone 8.1 silverlight  development . I need help in auto rotating mediaelement , when I turn phone vertical to horizontal.
Please help me in solving this issue.

Comment: go directly to Windows 10 UWP app development. Support for phone 8.1 ends in july 2017

Answer (score 0):

How about you try this adding this to your page;

SupportedOrientations="PortraitOrLandscape" Orientation="Portrait"

just like in this example

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"

    x:Class="Yourproject.Page1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    SupportedOrientations="PortraitOrLandscape" Orientation="Portrait"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="False" Background="#FF0F0F0F">
```